# Darksiders 3 Armors

Tags: darksiders-3

So with the new Darksiders game I was wondering if there is actually armor with effects like less damage or such. I only got the cosmetic armor so far from season pass but as it says, its purely cosmetic.

**So the question is, are there armors with an actual effect?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of "The Crucible" DLC, 3 armors have been released officially. They can be bought at the crucible shop.

- Chaos Bringer's Armor:

  - Unlocked at wave 50
  - Costs 60 coins
  - +10% Physical Damage
  - +10% Physical Damage Reduction
  - +20% Health
- Reaper's Shadow Mail:

  - Unlocked at wave 75
  - Costs 60 coins
  - +15% Arcane Damage
  - +10% Lurchers When Killing An Enemy
  - +60 Health Regenerated Per Minute
- Panoply of Champions:

  - Unlocked at wave 100
  - Costs 60 coins
  - +10.8% Amount of Havoc Bar Generated Per Minute
  - +20% Havoc Form Duration
  - +30% Wrath Reward From Wrath Lurchers

Answer (score 2):

There are three armours with effects that can be obtained through the console. Here's the list:
[image: Darksiders 3 hidden armours]
Those will probably be the ones featured in the upcoming DLCs.
Instructions to enable the console on PC http://fearlessrevolution.com/viewtopic.php?t=8318

Comment: Do you also have a source for the list?

Comment: It's in the link. I also enabled the console and cheated those in myself.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage, there is not much information.

However, it is confirmed that the Abyssal Armour is going to make a reappearance - however only if you [purchase the DLC](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/462163-darksiders-3-abyssal-armor-how-to-get-location-dlc).

I can't say for certain that this armour *will* have any particular "effects", though the trend says it *should*, but again, since the effect has been different from game to game, only time will tell what that effect is.