# Does Darksiders 3 have a 'New Game Plus' mode?

Tags: darksiders-3

I finished my first playthrough of *Darksiders 3*, and there was no option to choose to replay the game and keep my progress. As the previous game (Darksiders II) had a New Game Plus mode, I thought that there might be a similar mode in this game.

It is rather typical for this kind of game to have a New Game Plus, simply to explore the game with a whole other view. As it stands, it is not possible to max out all weapons and enchants in a single playthrough.

So is it possible to start a "New Game plus" in *Darksiders 3* and if so, how can I start it?

Comment: Both Darksiders 1 and 2 had NG+. It's entirely reasonable to expect 3 to have one, as well. As a matter of fact, this is the first hit I got googling "Darksiders 3 new game plus", because I was confused that I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have NG+ aka Armageddon mode as of Patch 4 of April 11, 2019.

Answer (score 4):

There is no NG+.

Not all games do have an NG+ mode, though since the previous installments did have an NG+, it might be understandable that Darksiders 3 would too.

However, it has been revealed that the [Abyssal armour is to be released in a future DLC pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/341697/73976), there is potential that the "NG+ mode" will be released in a later pack as well.

[Source](https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Darksiders/comments/a0rrfc/i_finished_darksiders_3_and_there_is_no_ng_mode/).